# Windows Media Player 11 Not Detecting Autoplaylists

Tags: windows-media-player, playlists

Every time I open Windows Media Player it fails to detect my autoplaylists stored in `<my music library dir>\Playlists`. This appears to lead to sync problems since I (exclusively) use autoplaylists to sync music to my mobile. As WMP 11 fails to find the any sync autoplaylists it infuriatingly seems to decide that I want no music at all on my phone and proceeds to delete all my music off my phone.

I guess these are two seperate problems but it seems to me they are related. If anyone can shed any light on a fix, that would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Solution: Use something other then Windows Media Player OR move the autoplaylists to a location that can be found always.  How a WMP on a desktop deletes your music on your phone confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using XP or Vista?

If you press F3 in WMP and expand the **Advanced Options**, is your music library dir being monitored by WMP, i.e. listed and not set to **Ignore**?